# jquery ajax post method error in Code

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

The problem with this code is when I run it and I try to enter john into the username field and click register, `hello` is not printed. `hello again` is printed in every situation this means that the data is not sent to the process.php file. The reason for this is $.post is not working

What could be wrong?

index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Registration System</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
label{
    display:block;
}
input{
    display:block;
}
</style>
<body>
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <form id="login">
        <label>UserName</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="pwd" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
    </form>
    <h1>Registration form</h1>
    <form id="register">
        <label>UserName</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" />
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="pwd" name="password" placeholder="password" />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
    <p id="paragraph"></p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head> 
</body>
</html>
```

script.js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#register").submit(function(){

        var username=$("#username").val();
        var pwd=$("#pwd").val();
        var email=$("#email").val();

        $.post("process.php",{username:username,pwd:pwd,email:email},function(data){

            $("#paragraph").html(data);

        });

        return false;

      });

});
```

process.php file

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username']))
{

$username = $_POST['username'];

if($username == "john")
{
    echo "hello";
}
else{
    echo "hello again";
}

}


?>
```

Comment: You have duplicate IDs - do not have the same ID since jQuery will not work using `$("#username")` etc - I have voted to close as something that cannot be reproduced - since your code will work if you use unique IDs or get the username using another selector

Comment: pass your `username` javascript variable to your console and see

Comment: Feel free to delete.

Comment: @mplungjan he may keep the same IDs and using some parent inheritance, although i consider this a poor practice.